# How do I show a section on print but hide it on screen?

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet

I want to hide an image/logo on screen but want it to display on print. My efforts have not been working though. What's wrong with my code?

```
<style>
@media print {
   #othersections, #ebooknav {display: none;}
   #test {width: 100%; margin-top: 150px;}
   #printlogo {display: block; margin-top: 0px;}
             }
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
<div id="printlogo" style="display: none;"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></div>
<div id="test" style="margin-right:220px; float:left;">
Content to be printed
</div>
<div id="ebooknav">
<a href="" title="Print Page" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="/printbutton.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `display: none` is in an inline style attribute, which will always override any CSS in your `<style>` tags by default. I don't think you should use inline styles here at all, unless you can't modify your HTML.

Comment: what other options do I have to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I think I finally figured it out by removing the inline styling. many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a clue from BoltClock. I realized that this is due to a conflict in the priority of styling. Styles may override one another according to the following (source: [w3schools: cascading order of multiple styles](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)):

1. Inline style (inside an HTML element) - highest priority
2. Internal style sheet (in the head section)
3. External style sheet
4. Browser default - lowest priority

In the problem above, I removed the inline styling and put it in the internal style sheet instead, or I may also just put it in the external stylesheet later:

```
<style>
@media screen {
   #printlogo {display: none;}
              }
@media print {
   #othersections, #ebooknav {display: none;}
   #test {width: 100%; margin-top: 150px;}
   #printlogo {display: block; margin-top: 0px;}
             }
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
<div id="printlogo"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></div>
<div id="test" style="margin-right:220px; float:left;">
Content to be printed
</div>
<div id="ebooknav">
<a href="" title="Print Page" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="/printbutton.png" /></a>
</div>
```

and it finally worked!